# Is it possible to use a AV-receiver output for an "active" speaker?

Tags: speakers, receiver

I have a 5.1 output and I'd like to use the center-chanel output for a soundbar. The soundbar is active (has optic, coaxial and 3.5 mm jack). 
Is any way to convert the output of the center-channel from the AV-receiver to an output compatible with an active speaker?

(Coaxial/optic does not work when 5.1 audio is activated, and anyway it is not the desired effect, for I want only the center chanel in the soundbar).

Comment: Is the 5.1 output line level (RCA/Cinch connectors) or speaker level?

Comment: @peufeu They are like the ones for center in [this picture](http://www.grrpicturehosting.co.uk/SixBit_2/January2015/162124-08.jpg). Can I plug the cables to a RCA end and then a RCA to 3.5mm jack converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you have speaker-level outputs.

If the 5.1 amp has "pre-out" use that.

Otherwise you need an adapter [like this](https://www.parts-express.com/high-to-low-adapter-with-male-rcas--269-050).

You can make it yourself, it's just a resistor divider, dead simple:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6vzMx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

HOWEVER if your amp is bridged, like some of the recent class-D ones, then you're out of luck because the "ground" speaker terminal isn't "ground", rather it is the output of the second half of the bridged amp. You should check that before doing anything. Just use a multimeter continuity tester to check the speaker "-" terminal connects to the other speakers "-" terminals for instance.